# MAC File handling via remote management

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-handling

Overview: Files are not getting deleted in File Manager when user tries to edit the file and admin deletes the file at the same time.

Description:
Actually I have created a text file on my desktop. Using remote login with super user to my desktop from other system I have deleted that file. Meanwhile on my system I am editing that file.

But I am confused to see that file is not getting deleted from my desktop.

I am using removeItemAtPath method of FileManager to delete the file, when file is deleted using remote management.

```
-(BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

Please provide me an alternative for the file handling for removing file. Or any other solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the method return? If `NO`, what does the error object indicate?

Comment: @BenZotto: I checked ... method returns YES. It passes without any error.